# API endpoints with protocol version

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

Does anyone know what is the significance of including the protocol version in the api endpoint in an API specifications document?

Example:

```
 /pet/findByTags **HTTP/1.1**:
    get:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Finds Pets by tags
      description: Multiple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.
      operationId: findPetsByTags
      parameters:
        - name: tags
          in: query
          description: Tags to filter by
          required: false
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
```

When I use this as mentioned above, the swagger editor doesn't complain, but I am not sure about the purpose of this.

I tried looking in details at the OpenApi specifications but it doesn't mention the scenario above.

Comment: That isn’t part of open api to do that. That’s the area for a path template

Comment: Sorry, didn't follow that. What isn't part of Open API? Obviously whatever specs we write needs to conform to the specifications.

Comment: That HTTP version part is going to be part of the path

Comment: It's part of the path only as I mentioned above. But what is the significance of mentioning the protocol version here. Let's say we have multiple paths mentioned in the specification document.
/order/basket HTTP/1.1
/order/basket/{id} HTTP/2

is this a valid scenario? if yes, then why is it required?

Comment: that's up to who wrote that api spec. having that there means your request has to look like `GET /pet/findByTags%20HTTP/1.1` or `GET /order/basket/{id}%20HTTP/2`

Answer (score 0):

the http protocol version is not specifically defined in the OpenAPI Specification and is not recognized or supported in any way. The spec assumes the use of "HTTP apis" and only references `HTTP/1.1` when referring to `headers`, `status codes` and acceptable security `schemes`. HTTP/2 is backwards compatible and there are no significant changes to describe an HTTP/2 api over an HTTP/1.1 api in relation to the OpenAPI specification.  Any new header values required for HTTP/2 apis are defined in the same manner as HTTP/1.1 apis, following [RFC7230](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7230.html#field.extensibility). This RFC outlines how new header values shall be processed by implementations of the http specficiation.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Exactly what i was trying to find out.